# com.google.cast.DeviceManager no longer public?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I updated to the latest jar version and my compiler is claiming that com.google.cast.DeviceManager is no longer public?

Answer (score 0):

That class is still there and public in the preview SDK, what jar file did you download?

Comment: I got this one https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastSdkAndroid-1.0.6.zip that is listed on this page https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/ and just tried it again and it still shows as not public inside the jar (at least IntelliJ thinks so)

Comment: I have to double check that when I get to work. However, please keep in mind that the preferred way of doing discovery is to use the MediaRouter framework and we strongly recommend to move your code to use the MR instead of DeviceManger; even if it is supported for now (which may have already been stopped based on your observations), it will not be supported in future releases. Is there something that you need to do and cannot accomplish using the MR framework (for discovery portion)?

Comment: DeviceManager is **not** in the latest release.  @AliNaddaf, can you tell us when we might expect the Chromecast SDK to be released?  You and Les do a great job of responding here in SO, but I don't see another way for indie developers to communicate with the CC developer team.

Comment: I can't speak into any timeline (I know, it is frustrating to hear that, sorry!) but rest assured, we are really working hard to get there. We collected even more (very useful) feedback from our recent hackathon  that will help us to release the official version more aligned with the needs of our partners and our developer community. On the subject of DevicveManager, as I mentioned in my earlier remark, please stay away from that and try to adapt your code to MediaRouter for discovery purposes.

Comment: Thank you @AliNaddaf for the response.  I understand the challenges you face. I think a lot of the frustration comes from the lack of dialog.  Perhaps someone from your team could interact with the Chromecast community on G+.  Do you mind if I post your comment on G+?